# How to filter Helm chart of dependency

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using `helm template --show-only`, it is possible to only show a certain template. However it is unclear if this is supported for the dependencies of a chart as well. Is this supported, and if so, how does one construct the proper filter path?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the way to do this is via `--show-only charts/<alias>/templates/<template-name>.yaml`.